# Linker Error: symbol not DefinedRegular or Shared

Tags: c++, linker, clang

I am taking an existing project and updating it to use Clang.  I have version 3.9 installed and while I can compiler fine I am getting an error when linking.  I am using the linker provided by LLVM and compiling to an ARM target from Windows.

The linker error I get is: symbol not DefinedRegular or Shared

I'm not exactly sure what is wrong and Googling around doesn't seem to produce many results.  The linker isn't telling me which symbol or anything like that.  Thus the error message is pretty vague.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

EDIT:

The Linker Command: Running it on it's own produces the same cryptic error as running it via the makefile

```
C:/LLVM/bin/ld.lld.exe --sysroot=../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04 C:/Software/b2/D1_Common/software/application/base/executive/buildfiles/linux2-arm-release-obj/exec_arm.o C:/Software/b2/D1_Common/software/application/base/executive/buildfiles/linux2-arm-release-obj/exec_armplatform.o C:/Software/b2/D1_Common/software/application/base/executive/buildfiles/linux2-arm-release-obj/exec_rtc.o C:/Software/b2/D1_Common/software/application/base/executive/buildfiles/linux2-arm-release-obj/executive.o C:/Software/b2/D1_Common/software/application/base/executive/buildfiles/linux2-arm-release-obj/executivemain.o C:/Software/b2/D1_Common/software/application/base/executive/buildfiles/linux2-arm-release-obj/processregistry.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/exec_client.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/procstatus.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/statusLogClient.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/xmlLogClient.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/statusLogBuf.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/xmlLogBuf.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/engLogBuf.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/logBuf.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/statusLogMsg.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/xmlLogMsg.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/engLogMsg.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/logMsg.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/statusLogFile.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/xmlLogFile.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/engLogFile.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/engLogTable.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/engLogEntry.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/treatmentLogMsg.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/treatmentHistoryMsg.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/flowsheetMsg.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/alertsAlarmsMsg.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/logFile.o ../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/notifierSharedMemory.o -L../build/linux2-arm-release-obj -lutil -lplutodb -losi -lutil -lsyserror -lxml2 -lsqlite3 -lssl -lgcrypt -lcrypto -lpthread -lrt -luuid -L ../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi -L ../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi -o ../build/linux2-arm-release-image/executive

symbol not DefinedRegular or Shared
```

Here is the linker output via the makefile:

```
symbol not DefinedRegular or Shared    
make: *** [executive] Error 1
```

Here is the verbose linker output via the makefile:

```
C:/Software/b2/D1_Common/software/application/base/executive/buildfiles/linux2-arm-release-obj/exec_arm.o    
C:/Software/b2/D1_Common/software/application/base/executive/buildfiles/linux2-arm-release-obj/exec_armplatform.o    
C:/Software/b2/D1_Common/software/application/base/executive/buildfiles/linux2-arm-release-obj/exec_rtc.o   
C:/Software/b2/D1_Common/software/application/base/executive/buildfiles/linux2-arm-release-obj/executive.o   
C:/Software/b2/D1_Common/software/application/base/executive/buildfiles/linux2-arm-release-obj/executivemain.o   
C:/Software/b2/D1_Common/software/application/base/executive/buildfiles/linux2-arm-release-obj/processregistry.o   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/exec_client.o   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/procstatus.o  
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/statusLogClient.o  
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/xmlLogClient.o  
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/statusLogBuf.o   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/xmlLogBuf.o      
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/engLogBuf.o    
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/logBuf.o    
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/statusLogMsg.o    
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/xmlLogMsg.o   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/engLogMsg.o     
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/logMsg.o    
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/statusLogFile.o    
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/xmlLogFile.o    
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/engLogFile.o   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/engLogTable.o   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/engLogEntry.o   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/treatmentLogMsg.o    
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/treatmentHistoryMsg.o   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/flowsheetMsg.o    
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/alertsAlarmsMsg.o   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/logFile.o    
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj/notifierSharedMemory.o    
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj\libutil.a   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj\libplutodb.a   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj\libosi.a   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj\libutil.a   
../build/linux2-arm-release-obj\libsyserror.a   
../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi\libxml2.so   
../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi\libsqlite3.so    
../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi\libssl.so   
../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi\libgcrypt.so   
../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi\libcrypto.so   
../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi\libpthread.so   
../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libpthread.so.0   
../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libpthread_nonshared.a    
../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi\librt.so   
../common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi\libuuid.so   
symbol not DefinedRegular or Shared   
make: *** [executive] Error 1
```

Comment: First, search for "stackoverflow c++ symbol not found".  Secondly, edit your post with the exact error message and also the command line used.

Comment: That is the exact error message.  It's literally says "symbol not Defined Regular or Shared".  I don't think it's an undefined symbol.  It will say if it can't find X

Comment: All the compilers and linkers that I've used *state the symbol name that is not defined*.

Comment: Is the error from the linker or the make utility?  Try running the linker without using the make utility.

Comment: The error is form the linker.  Running it own it's own produces the same error as with the make file.  I update first post again with the link line.